# Raspberry Pi - Network cannot connect on one wifi connection, but can another

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi

I setup my raspberry pi with a wifi connection (from a wifi extender), and had no issues. I could connect to the internet, everything was great.

I then changed my wifi extender, so went to my raspberry pi and logged into the new wireless.  It says its connected to the wireless, but I can no longer connect to the internet or the network.   Any thoughts??  When I switch back to my original wifi connection / extender, it works fine again.

Thanks

EDIT:  This seems to be related to this!
https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/1542

Comment: With the XP/rep you have here, you should know that SO is a place for programming related questions that require code. If you did a quick search, you'd have found the [Raspberry Pi SE](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, I honestly dislike wireless. You could always get a Ethernet cable and plug it in, and it'll never do the error again. You can find them very cheap, and it's faster than wireless.

But, for some friendly Raspberry Pi reference, if you have another computer (it doesn't matter how old or slow, it'll work either way), you can [download VNC Viewer](https://www.realvnc.com/download/vnc/), plug in your Ethernet cable to your Raspberry Pi (or you can use a WiFi adapter too!!), then [find your Raspberry Pi's IP address](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ip-address.md), and use VNC Viewer to control your Raspberry Pi from that other computer. That's what I'm doing.

I hope I help with this :)

Comment: thanks!  unfort the wired solution isn't possible because the Pi is outside, vs router inside...

Comment: I'm glad to help out!! You can also use a WiFi adapter to do this, too! If it already has that don't worry! It'll still work though! And I'm sorry about that, If I knew that, I would've... actually, IDK. You could try to turn off your router for 30 seconds and turn it on again. That might work!